# BindingAdpater is not working at recyclerview

Tags: android

I set up BindingAdpater at recyclerview items. But when I get from data, it doesn't not work.
as you see below, myItem is working. But not working at items that is in parameter. I don't understand why items(in parameter) is not working.

*BindingAdapter*

```
@BindingAdapter("app:items")
fun setItems(view: RecyclerView, items: List<LaunchListQuery.Launch>?) {
    var myItem = arrayListOf<LaunchListQuery.Launch?>()
    myItem.add(LaunchListQuery.Launch("","Id : "+1,"Site : "+1,null))
    myItem.add(LaunchListQuery.Launch("","Id : "+2,"Site : "+2,null))
    myItem.add(LaunchListQuery.Launch("","Id : "+3,"Site : "+3,null))
    (view.adapter as MainAdapter).submitList(items)
}
```

*xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.haii.graphqldemo.main.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:items="@{viewmodel.items}"/>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

*ViewModel*

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: DefaultRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _items :MutableLiveData<List<LaunchListQuery.Launch?>> = MutableLiveData()
    val items : LiveData<List<LaunchListQuery.Launch?>> = _items
    fun getItems(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val items = repository.getLaunchList()
            _items.value = items.launches
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding

*onCreate at Activity*

`binding.lifecycleOwner = this`

*onActivityCreated at Fragment*

`binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner`